# Change Laptop HDD with older one

Tags: windows-10

I recently (about 6 months ago) I upgraded my recently passed away mother's laptop (Dell) to Windows 10 (after confirming that it met all criteria) but the HDD died on me a few weeks after.

I've got another laptop (HP) that has other hardware problems that I know the HDD runs fine.

My question is if I swap the HDD in the Dell laptop what other problems can I expect? (Besides the more than obvious driver installations for hours on end!)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without knowing more information such as the model and windows versions, hardware, etc.

You can try booting off the HDD externally first to see if you get any issues.

However I would strongly recommend a fresh windows install if you do plan on using the hard drive from your HP laptop. If you do, you should not get any driver issues.

Answer (score 0):

Change hard drives between laptops, we need to consider many factors. For example, the size of HDD, the interface (SATA/IDE/etc) of HDD, operating system, software and some drivers for the hardware.The most important thing is whether we can start the computer normally.

If the computer is replaced with hardware, it is highly recommended that we reinstall the operating system. If we directly replace the hardware, we may not be able to boot due to the motherboard driver problem. Reinstalling the system and reinstalling the driver generally does not cause problems.